# React components spams read on firebase collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So recently i tried making a chat app using React and firebase, to learn these tools. It goes very well, but for some reason it seems that whenever the database is active it spams read on the collection, even with no changes. I suspect some element is rerendering in an infinite loop, but i can't seem to fix it. Any suggestions for how i can display messages and only update whenever a new change is made to the collection?

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';


import './App.css';


import Navbar from './Navbar';


firebase.initializeApp({
// My configs are here
})

const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();


function App() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <section className="place-content-end">
        {user ? <ChatRoom /> : <SignIn />}
        <SignOut />
      </section>
    </>
  );
}


function SignIn() {

  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button className="sign-in ml-20 pl-5" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google to join! </button>
      <p className="ml-20 pl-5">Welcome to the chat!</p>
    </>
  )

}

function SignOut() {
  return auth.currentUser && (
    <button className="sign-out ml-20 pl-5" onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
  )
}

function ChatRoom() {
  const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
  const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(50);
  const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App ml-20 pl-5">
        <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
        <main>
          {messages && messages.map(msg => <DisplayMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />)}
        </main>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}


function DisplayMessage(props) {
  const { text, uid } = props.message;
  return (<>
    <div>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  </>)
}


export default App;
```

And my firebase looks like this after a few minutes online on my local server

[image]

Comment: It looks alright to me. My only guess it keeps re-rendering and I would use `useEffect` to load the data on ChatRoom mount and this will ensure messages are loaded only once, then maybe subscribe to a message listener (and unsubscribe on unmount) if you want to listen for changes.

Comment: Also make use of `useState`, I see you imported it but it's not used, one of the advantages of React is state management of components.

Comment: I think i should already be subscribing to changes with the `useCollectionData`. But i also figured the problem is an infinite loop of re-rendering. Why it is happening, i can not seem to grasp. But thank you for the input - `useState` is gone for now :) I am using both `firebase-react-hooks` and normal `react-hooks`

Comment: It seems to have something to do with the rendering of ChatRoom and  
`
  const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
  const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(50);
  const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });
`

Since even after removing 
`
{messages && messages.map(msg => <DisplayMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />)}
`
it still took me above 70K reads in 10 minutes tops.

Sorry.. I don't know how to properly format this message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

import { useAuthState } from "react-firebase-hooks/auth";
import { useCollectionData } from "react-firebase-hooks/firestore";

import "./App.css";

import Navbar from "./Navbar";

firebase.initializeApp({
// My configs are here
});

const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();

function App() {
const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
return (
    <>
    <div className="App">
        <Navbar />
    </div>
    <section className="place-content-end">
        {user ? <ChatRoom /> : <SignIn />}
        <SignOut />
    </section>
    </>
);
}

function SignIn() {
const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
};
return (
    <>
    <button className="sign-in ml-20 pl-5" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
        Sign in with Google to join!{" "}
    </button>
    <p className="ml-20 pl-5">Welcome to the chat!</p>
    </>
);
}

function SignOut() {
return (
    auth.currentUser && (
    <button className="sign-out ml-20 pl-5" onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>
        Sign Out
    </button>
    )
);
}

function ChatRoom() {
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const messagesRef = firestore.collection("messages");
    const query = messagesRef.orderBy("createdAt").limit(50);
    const [data] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: "id" });
    setMessages(data);
}, []);

return (
    <>
    <div className="App ml-20 pl-5">
        <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
        <main>
        {messages.length > 0 &&
            messages.map((msg) => (
            <DisplayMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />
            ))}
        </main>
    </div>
    </>
);
}

function DisplayMessage(props) {
const { text, uid } = props.message;
return (
    <>
    <div>
        <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
    </>
);
}

export default App;
```

I added `useEffect` in line 1. And changed your `ChatRoom` component.

Quick explanation

`useEffect` is part of the lifecycle of a Function Component. You give it a function to execute whenever the component mounts or props or state of the component changes. You decide this by what you add as the second argument of the `useEffect` call. If you give it an `[]` (empty array), it will only execute when the component is mounted. If you give, for example, `[messages]` (which a state created by `useState`) then the function will execute on component mount AND whenever `messages` change. React keeps track of this for you, this is why React is called react, if data changes it reacts to it and renders accordingly.

The above explanation is the basics of it. But there is also one more cool thing it can do:

If you return a function from inside of `useEffect`, this function will execute when the component is UNmounted. Like so:

```
useState(() => {
    console.log("Component mounted");

    return () => {
    console.log("Component unmounted");
    };
},[]);
```

In Class Components we have similar functions, they are called: componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount and others.You can read about it here [React State & Lifecyle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)